# Forward directory path string from Android to Lucene library

Tags: java, android, lucene

I am trying to forward directory path string from Android to Lucene library, but geting this error:

> W/System.err: org.apache.lucene.store.NoSuchDirectoryException: directory '/file:/android_asset' does not exist

```
public void setLockFactory(LockFactory lockFactory) throws IOException {
    super.setLockFactory(lockFactory);

    if (lockFactory instanceof FSLockFactory) {

        FSLockFactory lf = (FSLockFactory)lockFactory;
        File dir = lf.getLockDir();

        if (dir == null) {
            lf.setLockDir(this.directory);
            lf.setLockPrefix((String)null);
        } else if (dir.getCanonicalPath().equals(this.directory.getCanonicalPath())) {
            lf.setLockPrefix((String)null);
        }
    }
}

public static String[] listAll(File dir) throws IOException {
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        throw new NoSuchDirectoryException("directory '" + dir + "' does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: In my Android project I sent : String indexDir = ("file:///android_asset/Index");

Comment: The file or project is in android project or in sdcard?

Comment: Assets are not files, and `file:///android_asset/index` is not a filesystem path. If Lucene supports reading from an `InputStream`, use `AssetManager` and `open()` to get an `InputStream` on your asset. If Lucene only works with files, use the `InputStream` from `open()` to copy the asset to a file (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`), then use Lucene with that file.

Comment: My case is second , can you show example how to do this?